# Getting Test Case List from QC using Com4j

Tags: java, hp-quality-center, com4j

I have written the following code to retrieve the list of Test Cases from QC, but the `tsTestFactory` is null, whereas when I evaluate `qcConnect.testSetFactory()` it returns a Com4j object.

What am i doing wrong here

```
ITestSetFactory tsFactory = (qcConnect.testSetFactory()).queryInterface(ITestSetFactory.class);
ITestSetTreeManager tsTreeMgr = (qcConnect.testSetTreeManager()).queryInterface(ITestSetTreeManager.class);

ITestSetFolder tsFolder = (tsTreeMgr.nodeByPath(nodePath)).queryInterface(ITestSetFolder.class);
IList its1 = tsFolder.findTestSets(testSetName, false, "");

Iterator itr = its1.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    Com4jObject comObj = (Com4jObject) itr.next();
    ITestSet sTestSet = comObj.queryInterface(ITestSet.class);
    System.out.println(sTestSet.name());
    System.out.println(sTestSet.id());

    ITestFactory tsTestFactory = (qcConnect.testSetFactory()).queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
    ITSTest sTSTest = (tsTestFactory.item(sTestSet.id())).queryInterface(ITSTest.class);

    System.out.println(sTSTest.name());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The TestFactory is not the same as the TestSetFactory, so you can't do this:

ITestFactory tsTestFactory = (qcConnect.testSetFactory()).queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);

Try qcConnect.testFactory instead of qcConnect.testSetFactory.